# How to omit fields in object spread?

Tags: typescript

I have one interface with many fields and other interface with almost all fields (just one less).

**How in TypeScript** without untyped unsafe crutches (`<>`, `as`, `any`, `unknown` and similar) **can one exclude fields in object spread** (so without enumerating every field I want to copy)?

```
interface A {
    fieldA: number;
    fieldB: string;
    fieldC: number;
    fieldD: string;
    fieldE: number;
    fieldF: string;
}

interface B {
    fieldA: number;
    fieldB: string;
    fieldC: number;
    fieldD: string;
    fieldE: number;
    // no fieldF here
}

const a: A = {
    fieldA: 1,
    fieldB: 'b',
    fieldC: 3,
    fieldD: 'd',
    fieldE: 5,
    fieldF: 'f'
}

const b: B = {
    ...a,
    fieldF: undefined
};
```

This doesn't compile, because fieldF is still present, only have a value of `undefined`.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you don't mind an intermediate step, you can do something like this:

```
const { fieldF, ...everythingExceptF } = a;
const b: B = everythingExceptF;
```

This combines the [spread and rest operators](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/12/23/typescript-2-1-object-rest-and-spread). The compiler seemed happy with this on my machine, and it gives me the result you'd expect.

Note: this will also create the constant `fieldF`, which you may or may not want. If you already need that name for some other reason in the same scope, you can reassign it like this:

```
const { fieldF: someOtherName, ...everythingExceptF } = a;
```

Comment: This is a nice way to do it, but unfortunately it will throw an error if linting `no-unused-vars`

Comment: That's true - depending on the linter and your configuration you'll either need to prefix the variable with "_" to flag it as intentionally unused or just annotate that error away.

Answer (score 1):

If you wan to remove the field you can:

```
const copy: A = {
    ...a
};

delete copy.fieldF;

const b: B = copy;
```

But you don't have to:

```
const b: B = {
    ...a
};
```

Compiler is ok with it.